# Alternate casing of letters in a string in C

Tags: c, string

Need help in converting a example string like this: 
 `Example   String` 
 into: 
 `eXaMpLe   StRiNg`
 by preserving the whitespaces In C Programming language. I referred to other posts, but didn't find any help for writing in C.

I tried using this logic:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i,len;
    char a[30],b[30];

    printf("Enter a string\n");
    gets(a);
    len=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<len;i=i+2)
    {

        if(a[i]!=' ' && isalpha(a[i]))
        {
            a[i]=tolower(a[i]);
        }
        else if(a[i]!=' ')
            a[i]=toupper(a[i]);
    }
    printf("New string is %s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of help did you need? You should design an algorithm first. Once you have that the language is just a tool to put it into action (C or otherwise). If you're asking us to do your homework for you, you're on the wrong site.

Comment: Sorry, let me post a sample code i used now.

Comment: [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64941099/edit) to include that code, and explain what problems you seem to be having, including the actual input and resulting output from your tests.

Comment: Done, updated the questions with code and sample input and output. Please help me in getting the alternate casing

Comment: You forgot the *actual* output part of your code. And ideally it's a [mcve] (you're missing headers, a `main`, variable declarations, etc.)

Comment: Ok, let me upload complete code now

Comment: Never ***ever*** use `gets`! It's such a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function it has even been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Sure, please help me in loop iteration for getting alternative casing on string

Comment: As for your problem, you need to modify *all* letters, right now you're skipping every second letter and leave its casing as it is. You also need to keep a state (a variable) for the last letter, if it was upper or lower case.

Comment: Sorry didn't get your answer. Please post a sample code inside the for loop with changes.

Comment: The example you provided does not have white spaces, post an example with white spaces or multiple words

Comment: @IrAM How does `Example   String` *not* have white spaces?

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I thought `Example` is not part of `Example   String`.

Comment: @IrAM the followup conversion result, `eXaMpLe   StRiNg` was the dead give-away to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, though it is unrelated to your problem, [you shouldn't use `gets ()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/11336762).

Then, what you need is just to `tolower()` the even elements of the string and to `toupper ()` the odd elements. We need to process **all** elements (you used to process just one every two elements).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i,len, alphas;
    char a[30],b[30];

    printf("Enter a string\n");
    fgets(a, 30, stdin);
    len=strlen(a);

    for(i=0, alphas=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(a[i]))
        {
            if(alpha%2 == 0)
            {
                a[i]=tolower(a[i]);
            }
            else
                a[i]=toupper(a[i]);

            alphas++;
        }
    }
}
```

We need to make sure that spaces don't count in our sequence, so we keep a variable `alphas` counting alphabetical chars. We understand if an index is even with modulus operator `%`, applied to our counter `alphas`.

Comment: And... the OP is missing `ctype.h`, which is required for the `toupper` and `tolower` operations.

Comment: This will convert `abc def` to `aBc dEf` instead of required `aBc DeF`.

Comment: @bereal I actually missed this requirement. I'll fix it.

Comment: For the sample input: ```i am pooja``` .
Got this output: ```i aM PoOjA```.
Expected output: ```i Am PoOjA```

Comment: @PoojaPNadiger check it now. I previously misunderstood this requirement.

Comment: @PoojaPNadiger As I mentioned, you need to keep the state of the *previous* letter, so you know how to modify the current letter.